# How do I define a function in Python using a "with open" logic?

Tags: python, list, function, variables

I am trying to define a function which creates a list of ordered pairs based on data received from a JSON file. I have created a data file ("contacts.txt") and stored data within that file. See code image here:

```
import json

# Generating false user data for purposes of testing. In production, this code will be modified to read individual JSON objects
# and combine them into one file.
# Assumes mobile application JSON tracks 2 contacts for each user
data = {}
data['contacts'] = []
data['contacts'].append({
    'userID': 'u1',
    'userPSEUDO': 'u1',
    'risk': '37',
    'lc1': 'u2',
    'lc2': 'u3',
})
data['contacts'].append({
    'userID': 'u2',
    'userPSEUDO': 'u2',
    'risk': '18',
    'lc1': 'u1',
    'lc2': 'u3',
})
data['contacts'].append({
    'userID': 'u3',
    'userPSEUDO': 'u3',
    'risk': '83',
    'lc1': 'u2',
    'lc2': 'u1',
})

with open('contacts.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

I then wrote a file which accesses the "contact.txt" data and generates ordered pairs from from that data. See code image here:

```
import json
# Need to define this code as a function
# def tracing_list():
with open('contacts.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data['contacts']:
    # Defining user dictionary to hold contact variables
        UserDict = {}
        A = 'userPSEUDO'
        B = 'lc1'
        C = 'userPSEUDO'
        D = 'lc2'
    # Populating user dictionary
    # This code prints the userPSEUDO as variables A and C and
    # prints the lc1 and lc2 as variables B and D. 
        UserDict[A] = p['userPSEUDO']
        UserDict[B] = p['lc1']
        UserDict[C] = p['userPSEUDO']
        UserDict[D] = p['lc2']
    # Printing contact ordered pairs from dictionary
        print(UserDict[A] + "," + UserDict[B])
        print(UserDict[C] + "," + UserDict[D])
```

This code outputs a set of ordered pairs for each "userPSEUDO" and the logged contacts contained within the JSON data. Each "userPSEUDO" has two stored contacts, with variables "lc1" and "lc2". The output is thus in the format of "userPSEUDO, lc1" and "userPSEUDO, lc2" for EACH distinct "userPSEUDO" (there are three, defined as "u1, u2, and u3") Thus, our output looks like this: (I divided it with separators for clarity, normally it is a list.)

u1,u2 |
u1,u3 |
u2,u1 |
u2,u3 |
u3,u2 |
u3,u1

I am trying to define a function called "tracing_list" that outputs this list dynamically and can be called from other parts of my program as needed. I am encountering a problem where the code runs perfectly when run without defining a function, BUT when I define a function and properly indent, it does not generate any output. It doesn't error either, it just does not generate the list. My code for the function is below:

```
import json
# Need to define this code as a function
def tracing_list():
    with open('contacts.txt') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for p in data['contacts']:
    # Defining user dictionary to hold contact variables
            UserDict = {}
            A = 'userPSEUDO'
            B = 'lc1'
            C = 'userPSEUDO'
            D = 'lc2'
    # Populating user dictionary
    # This code prints the userPSEUDO as variables A and C and
    # prints the lc1 and lc2 as variables B and D. 
            UserDict[A] = p['userPSEUDO']
            UserDict[B] = p['lc1']
            UserDict[C] = p['userPSEUDO']
            UserDict[D] = p['lc2']
    # Printing contact ordered pairs from dictionary
            print(UserDict[A] + "," + UserDict[B])
            print(UserDict[C] + "," + UserDict[D])
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I define my function with the code I already have?

Comment: When you define the function, do you call it from somewhere? Try putting a print statement at the top of the function to see if the code is entering into the function. There is nothing wrong with the code you have, but if you define it as a function, you must call the function in order for it to be run. That's the only thing I can think of that would be causing the code not to execute. Otherwise its all valid code.

Comment: @AlyT when I put a print statement at the top is still executes silently with no output. When I place a print statement at the bottom, it just outputs the memory location of the function: <function tracing_list at 0x7f5f947acdd0>

Comment: @WayneThornton You have to call the function, the same way you're "calling" the print function. Try adding this in the bottom of the file: `tracing_list()`

Comment: Where are you calling tracing_list from though? Somewhere in your code (not within the function definition) you need to have a line that calls ```tracing_list()```

Comment: @HampusLarsson thank you. I was adding "print(tracing_list)" at the bottom. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine for me :
[image]